# Cleaning up after killing off rabbit producers

Tags: rabbitmq, resource-cleanup

The crux of my problem is identifying how to clean up after a rabbit producer is killed off.

I have a rabbitmq environment with multiple producers and multiple consumers (workers).  Currently all messages (aka work) feeds into a central queue where the consumers pick up one message (work task) at a time and process.  Any given producer will generate ~800 messages of work which takes about 3 - 4 hours to complete.

The workers are cheerful folk who are task agnostic and can work on anything the producers dish out.  They work in a pull fashion because their work can take up to 10 minutes to complete per task.  Once they're ready for more work, they poll the queue.

The producers are a bit more fickle - sometimes they'll create a lot of work as messages on the queue and then decide they don't need that work done after all.  Worse, they'll sometimes generate a bunch of work; cancel all that; and then re-issue the work with different parameters.

I don't have a mechanism to ask the producers to requeue their work.  Part of the problem is they had *other* work that had to be done prior to pushing their requests onto the queue.

I <strike>can't</strike> don't want to just leave the work on the queue, as a single run from a producer represents 3 or 4 hours of work.  And my worst case scenario is where I have several producers backtrack on the work they requested while I have several other producers who want to keep their work on the queue.

So in that worst case, my queue would look like this and I need to clear out Prod B messages:

```
... | ~800 Prod A messages | ~800 Prod B messages | ~800 Prod C messages | ...
```

And I can't guarantee that the messages from A, B, and C aren't interleaved as I don't currently synchronize writes to the queue.

*What I've considered:*

- A simple queue purge would take out messages that I need to keep.
- I could write a dedicated consumer that pulls all the messages and requeues the good ones but that seems like a hack.

As an added challenge, I may need to support prioritization of a producer's work over others'.

All that said, **how can I clean up after a producer drops work onto the queue and then decides to cancel the work request?**

Answer (score 2):

I would create a secondary queue that's administrative, you occasionally drop messages on this queue to give out orders such as `PurgeQueue: C`, or `PrioritizeQueue: A`, or `PauseUntilISaySo` eventually followed by `OkYouMayPass`. Then all your workers simply check that queue/topic/whatever before the others they're actually working against (or if you just have an active dispatchable listener, make the one attached to your admin queue have some signal it can send to instruct workers to pause so it can process admin actions until it's done), and the rare occasions that it has a message they'll handle that then instead of their other queue's work.

If you get into a situation where you want to *remove* messages, I would instead encourage you to maintain an `ignoreList` in your workers, admin messages could be used to update it, so as soon as a producer decides "Wait, don't do the work in " it sends an admin message saying "Add to your ignore Queue: msgId1, msgId2, msgId3]", and the workers will pull that, add it to their ignore queue, and first thing they do with every work message they get is simply: Check their ignore queue to see if they should even work on that message

Comment: So you're suggesting a control signal that the workers use to modify how they handle future pulls?  In effect building a small rules engine within the workers?

Comment: @GlenH7 I would rather suggest a very simple control signal of pause/resume in your normal workers, and a *separate* worker that handles administrative actions, it can pause your worker-do the admin work- then resume the worker, this way your worker doesn't have to know anything about admin work, just how to pause/resume

Comment: OK, so that sounds like a modified version of the second bullet under what I already considered.  A dedicated admin consumer to clean things up as necessary.

Comment: @GlenH7 editted to clarify an approach to avoid having to purge and republish your queue when you want to remove a distinct possibly interleaved set of messages from the queue.